# How to bind Mandrill subaccount to dedicated IP

Tags: email, mandrill, bulk

I've created several subaccounts in Mandrill and I've bought a dedicated IP. Now I am wondering how to bind a given dedicated IP to a subaccount?

Actually I've created some rules to tell Mandrill that an email is sent from a given sender then what subaccount should be used and what IP pool should be used too. However I don't fully understand how emails will be sent and how reputation is determined for those subaccounts and dedicated IP. I've checked out Mandrill documentation but I couldn't find any clue.

Any help will be appreciated.